# Drop Down Menu bar

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

I'm developping a web app with Angular 4 and bootstrap,
I have this code that i'm using in a navigation sidebar that allows me to visualize a drop down menu element.
it was written in JavaScript, I made some syntax changes to turn it to a TypeScript method that is called each time a dropdown button is clicked.
The issue is that the button is not responsive til i click several times, twice most of the time, which gives a feeling that the sidebar is not responsive.
Is that related to the fact i didn't use this code in a  tag inside the html file and that the method is called from the component.ts file ?

`

```
onClickItem() {
    const dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-btn');
    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
      dropdown[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
        const dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (dropdownContent.style.display === 'block') {
          dropdownContent.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          dropdownContent.style.display = 'block';
        }
      });
    }
  }`
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverFlow. Your code is not running well because you should be doing this the angular way, which means adding logic, style and repeaters with angulars template synax: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax. Check it out and see if you can rebuild the above without extra JS or TS

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is because you should be using angulars syntax to do this. Template e.g.:

component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of dropdownItems" (click)="toggleHidden(item)" [class.hidden]="item.hidden">{{ item.text }}</li>
</ul>
```

component.ts

```
interface DropdownItem {
  text: string;
  id: string;
  hidden?: boolean;
}

public dropdownItems = [
 { text: 'item 1', id: '1' },
 { text: 'item 2', id: '2' },
 { text: 'item 3', id: '3' },
];

public toggleHidden(dropdownItem: DropdownItem) {
  dropdownItem.hidden = !dropdownItem.hidden
}
```

don't know the exact logic you are trying to achieve but this may give you some insight.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I had some issues in my css files, once fixed i used a ready template without using this method.